# Can I write all possible switch cases first and then there output?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case-statement

Hi I want to make a switch program where I want enter all switch cases first and then its output ..it should be like that

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Num from 1-10");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

switch (num)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:

         Console.WriteLine(1); break; 
         Console.WriteLine(2); break; 
         Console.WriteLine(3); break; 
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("wrong value entered");
        break;
}
```

means if the case is 2 ...then the output should be three...

Comment: Please be more clear in your question. It sounds like you want only 3 to the printed when the user enters 2. But you are currently writing 1, 2, and 3 when user enters 2. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: First I want to tell it c# I am working on.What I want is that I want to write all the switch cases first and then their outputs...Unlike we do in switch statements where we first put its case and then its out put

Comment: What you are saying is not possible. You must put each output next to each case statement. You cannot separate them like this.

Comment: The C# programming language doesn't work like this. What made you even _think_ about this?

Comment: No, you can't just make up your own syntax.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's an entire manual on the C# Programming Language. You should look at it before asking basic questions on the syntax of the language. See [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear in what language you are writing, but perhaps it's C++.

In any event, you cannot structure a switch statement like that in C++, C, or Java.  That's simply not how it works.  You can fall through from one case to the next in those languages, but you cannot jump to an arbitrary point in the code.  Directing where to jump based on the value of the switch expression is what the case labels are **for**.